# What exactly is the memory impact on the database when reducing cells size in a Raster GIS?

Tags: raster, database, file-size

I understand that the size of the memory of a raster database increases when reducing the cell resolution.
I read some about it in the [ArcGIS Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Cell_size_of_raster_data).

However, I am wondering about the exact relation on the memory footprint and was hoping that someone with more database-experience can tell me whether my reasoning here makes sense:

Given cells of 10x10 meters, and reducing the resolution to 5x5 meters, like so:

[image: reducing raster cell resolution]

The relation for the increase of number of cells would be `n*4`, so I thought that the memory increase in the database file would follow a similar pattern.

**Here's my attempt to generalize this:**

> The amount of cells and the memory size of the database both increase by the square of the number that the
>   sides of the initial raster cells are divided by.

E.g. `10/2` (`2` being the divisor, thus `2^2 = 4` being the factor in this case) results in `*4` the amount of cells - so does it also result in `*4` the amount of memory size of the database?

Given that my assumption is correct, dividing a raster cell by 4, e.g. `10/4` (with `4` being the divisor thus `4^2 = 16` being the factor), would  result in `*16` the amount of cells, and `*16` the amount of memory size of the database!
That would be a large increase of file size pretty quickly!

Is this generalized formula applicable or does the size of the database increase following a different pattern - and if so, which one?

Comment: The inverse-square law is generally correct.  The result could differ depending on how the data are stored.  For instance, subdividing a categorical grid that is stored using some form of compression might have no appreciable affect on the actual physical storage used.

Comment: I needed to reproject a 4-bit color-mapped raster, and found that resampling at a 1/5 interval was able to preserve the image annotation legibility  after reprojection, and was, on average, smaller than the original, poorly compressed raster, not 50 times larger (25 from pixels times 2 for rotation). There are too many permutations of format and compression algorithm and compressibility to make a generic answer to this question (and a specific case would have no usefulness to others). I would also note that *memory* is not applicable to rasters; it is disk storage which is significant.